# Is this question about Git appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, scope

Would the following question about troubleshooting Git on openSUSE be appropriate for Stack Overflow?

> I've just installed openSUSE, which came with Git version 1.8.1.4.
>
> However, the credential helper does not work. It spits out this message:
>
> ```
> error: cannot run git-credential-cache--daemon: No such file or directory  
> fatal: unable to start cache daemon: No such file or directory
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is suitable.

Git is a tool used by programmers, and tool support is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Do, however include as many details as you can - what you tried to make it work and how you set it up, for example.